# Regex in asp.net for allowing only characters with single space?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I want to allow a user to enter only characters and with single space in a textbox. What i have tried is :

```
^[\w\.:\(\)\[\]{}\-_](?: ?[\w\.:\(\)\[\]{}\-_])*$
```

it is blocking all but allowing digits also . How to make it correct such that it only allow characters and no digits but a single space between words? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use:

```
^[\p{L}.:()[\]{}_-]+(?: [\p{L}.:()[\]{}_-]+)*$
```

Where `\p{L}` stands for any letter.

*Edit:* 
I've changed `\pL` to `\p{L}` because it's not supported by `.NET`.
Thanks to Alan Moore.

Comment: +1, but .NET doesn't support the short form for "top level" Unicode properties like `\pL`; you have to use `\p{L}`.  Also, don't make the space optional; that's already handled by the `*` on the group.

Answer (score 0):

Is `([A-Za-z])+( [A-Za-z]+)` what you're after? Or do you want the regex to only match once?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there must be either oneor two 'words' (i.e. sequences of non-space characters)

```
"\s*[A-Za-z] +(\s[A-Za-z] +)?\s*"
```